# Disabling browser back button for specific url

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, browser, frontend

I want to disable the browser back button or say don't want to allow the user to navigate back from a specific url. Suppose the url is:

```
http://localhost/emptracker/#setup
```

So what I want it when user comes to this url the back button should get disabled. For now I read many Stack Overflow post and tried solutions like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    history.pushState(null, null, 'pagename');

    window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
        history.pushState(null, null, 'pagename');
    });

</script>
```

But the problem is that it disables the back button for the urls across the application and I want to do it for a specific url. My application is based on backbonejs.

Answer (score 0):

Use it . i think this is helpful for you

file1.html:

```
<form action="page2.html#no-back" method="post" />
  <input type="text" name="data" value="The data" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send data" />
</form>
```

file2.html

```
// It works without the History API, but will clutter up the history
var history_api = typeof history.pushState !== 'undefined'

// The previous page asks that it not be returned to
if ( location.hash == '#no-back' ) {
  // Push "#no-back" onto the history, making it the most recent "page"
  if ( history_api ) history.pushState(null, '', '#stay')
  else location.hash = '#stay'

  // When the back button is pressed, it will harmlessly change the url
  // hash from "#stay" to "#no-back", which triggers this function
  window.onhashchange = function() {
    // User tried to go back; warn user, rinse and repeat
    if ( location.hash == '#no-back' ) {
      alert("You shall not pass!")
      if ( history_api ) history.pushState(null, '', '#stay')
      else location.hash = '#stay'
    }
  }
}
```

[**Visit This Article working File**](http://jordanhollinger.com/2012/06/08/disable-the-back-button-using-html5/)

OR

[**Visit this Article with online demo**](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/)